# Laravel Breeze and Inertia JS problem with CORS Policy has block no "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Tags: cors, google-signin, google-sso

I have a problem when I tried to use Google SSO to my project, I have this issue:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=' (redirected from 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/google') from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Can someone also have this issue on Laravel breeze and inertia JS?

I try to login via Google and receive this issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe)